# Assigning Datetime value from sqlite db to datepicker in C# using wpf

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, datepicker, wpf-controls

I want to reading a datetime value from a Sqlite database and assign it to datepicker control. Here is my code that i am trying:

```
try
{
    sqlitecon.Open();
    string Query = "Select * from Customer_New where Cust_Id='" + val + "'  ";
    SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlitecon);
  //  createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while(dr.Read()){
        date_open.DisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(0));
       Date_Joining.DisplayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.GetString(1));     
        txt_Title.Text = dr.GetString(3);
    }                
    sqlitecon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

but it is giving error `specified cast is not valid`.until now no solution among two that are given below is working

Comment: And on what line might it be throwing that error?

Comment: try putting `test' GO DROP TABLE Customer GO --` in for val

Comment: Are the first and second field of your table of type date in Sqlite?

Comment: The above code is executed on form load event .so when form loads it should load the date value from db table into date picker .but form is opening with Message box of error "specified cast is not valid". Then it failed to load any value from db

Comment: @Steve :they of type datetime

Comment: I have tried this code: date_open.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(0);     it is giving error : "string was not recognize as a valid datatime"

Answer (score 0):

The exception is probably being thrown by the `SQLiteDataReader` as it is unable to convert a field value to string (maybe it is `DBNull`). If you have nullable fields in your table check for null values using the `IsDBNull` function first, before trying to read the value.
`Convert.ToDateTime()` throws a `FormatException` on error.

Comment: My db foramt is :MM/DD/YYYY ...here how to asign datepicker this format ?

Comment: Use `DateTime.ParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 0):

A good practice when you try to read data from a database table is to retrieve only the columns really needed by your subsequent code. In your example you retrieve everything from the table. The columns are returned in the same order in which they appear in the datatable. This means that the first column should be the value for your date_open and the second column the value for your data_join.

Probably a better approach is to explicitly say the name of the columns in your select query, use a parameter for the Cust_ID search key and use the GetDateTime of the reader instead of converting all to a string and the again to a date.

In this example I suppose that you have three columns in your table named `dateopen, datajoin and title`. You should use your real names instead.

```
try
{
     sqlitecon.Open();
     string Query = "Select dateopen, datejoin, title from Customer_New where Cust_Id=@id";
     SQLiteCommand createCommand = new SQLiteCommand(Query, sqlitecon);
     createCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", val);
     SQLiteDataReader dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();
     while(dr.Read())
     {
        // If there is the possibility of a NULL field then protect the assignement
        // with a check for DBNull.Value before the assignement
        if(!dr.IsDBNull(0))
            date_open.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(0));
        if(!dr.IsDBNull(1))
            Date_Joining.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(1));     
        if(!dr.IsDBNull(2))
            txt_Title.Text = dr.GetString(2);
    }                
    sqlitecon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: it is giving error : "string was not recognize as a valid datatime"

Comment: So, when the reader tries to get the first (or second) field it find a string that cannot be converted to a datetime. What is the value in the database for the first (or second) column relative at the id requested? What is your locale setting?

Comment: I have tried by using if(!dr.IsDBNull(1))
            date_open.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(1));
        if(!dr.IsDBNull(2))
            Date_Joining.DisplayDate = dr.GetDateTime(2));     
        if(!dr.IsDBNull(3))
            txt_Title.Text = dr.GetString(3); but it giving same error ....My db tables are Cust_id  | date_open  | Date_Joining |.....

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint on the first line, when the code flows hit the breakpoint you should be able to see the content of the reader fields and verifiy if you have really a datetime in the expected position

Comment: and if i remove date fields from assigning in while loop ..rest of text fields are assigned correctly .....Can it be the problem of Date Format ...My db format in db is :MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: A datetime is a datetime. The datetime value is not stored in a particular STRING format. The format is meaningful only for us when we want to display on video/print.

Comment: Try with this, instead of assign to the DisplayDate property try to assign the value obtained from GetDateTime to a temp variable of DateTime. If you get the error on this line the problem is the value stored in the db.

Comment: DateTime temp = dr.GetDateTime(1);   //it is giving error : "string was not recognize as a valid datatime" same error ..How to solve problem of value stored in db?